# Draw part of an image inside html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw the first Green tank inside my canvas but i think i am missing something in my code

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/B2nUs/1/)**:

```
draw: function () {
    tankImg.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(tankImg, this.Pos * this.w, 0, this.w, this.h, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    };
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, first of all thanks so much for the fiddle - makes everything a billion times easier.

There are <s>two</s> three errors in your code - the first is the tankImg.onload function. The onload function only fires once - when the image first loads.

What you want is tankImg.complete which will return true if loaded and false if not.

Secondly, you cannot assign 'ch - this.h' for the y property because 'this' isn't defined until, well, you finish defining it. What you can do is set the y value in your draw code.

Thirdly in javascript you can't do var cw, ch = 400;

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var cw = 400;
     var ch = 400;
     var ctx = $("#MyCanvas")[0].getContext("2d");
     var tankImg = new Image();
     tankImg.src = "http://oi62.tinypic.com/148yf7.jpg";
     var Fps = 60;
     var PlayerTank = {
         x: cw / 2,
         w: 84,
         h: 84,
         Pos: 2,
         draw: function () {
             ctx.drawImage(tankImg, this.Pos * this.w, 0, this.w, this.h, this.x, ch - this.h, this.w, this.h);
         }
     };

     var game = setInterval(function () {
         if (tankImg.complete) {
             PlayerTank.draw();
             PlayerTank.x++;
         }
     }, 1000 / Fps);
 });
```

Here is the completed [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2nUs/3/) with bonus movement for fun.

Edit: Ken's version of handling the .onload is much better.

Comment: thank you so much for answers guys i really appreciate it .i still need to ask one more question as u can see the tank image is so big 84x84 can i re-size it's width and height within my code or i should re-size the whole image ?

Comment: @Sora very easy, the last two arguments of drawImage is the width and height that you want to draw. Try changing them from `this.w` and `this.h` to `this.w/2` and `this.h/2` respectively (will halve the size).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few minor issues with the code which prevents:

1. Image to be loaded properly
2. Some uninitialized variables
3. Some inaccessible variables

The first variable that is undefined (producing `NaN` for the `drawImage()` method) is:

```
var cw; /// is not defined
```

The second more important issue is the way you handle the image loading.

You are currently setting the `onload` handler *inside* the draw method and re-setting it for each frame. Here the `onload` will probably not be caught and using the draw code inside it will at best only draw the image once as `onload` is only called once.

Change the code around a little like this:

```
var tankImg = new Image();
tankImg.onload = start;      /// add the onload handler before setting src.
tankImg.src = "http://oi62.tinypic.com/148yf7.jpg";
```

Then move your invoke of `setInterval` to `start`:

```
var game;   /// keep this var outside (in global)

function start() {
    game = setInterval(function () {
        PlayerTank.draw();
    }, 1000 / Fps);
}
```

The third issue is that `this.h` is not defined when you try to use it. Add a manual value (as in the modified fiddle) or wait until `draw()` is called to calculate it.

Now it should work:

### [Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/B2nUs/2/)